# nexus 4 red light flashing ,unresponsive

Tags: nexus-4

my nexus 4 , almost 1 month old, died all of a sudden ,only thing its doing nw is flashing a red light on charging. Cant switch it on or even cant reboot. As discussed in the this form i initially thought its complete battery drainage issue. so i kept the phone charging for almost 24hrs ....still no use... i bought it frm US thru my cousin and im staying outside  , so its not kind of easy for warranty claiming also .

Comment: Can you force a reboot (press the pwr button for 10s)? Or can you enter the Nexus' fastboot mode (when switched off, press and hold both vol-down+power buttons until you see a green Android.

Comment: I tried all that , but nothing works. i even took the phone to LG service center where thy have no idea about the phone ,But the managed to open the back cover and battery but still the phone is not switching on. What to do ,,,!!!!

Comment: @DragonLord I don't believe this is a duplicate. In the question you suggest, the problem was resolved by leaving the phone to charge for a while. In this case, the OP says that he's tried that and it didn't fix the problem.